# How would one do a for loop in a cucumber feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a set of preferences I want to test the exact same tests for, and make sure they all behave appropriately. So, the for loop would iterate over each preference configuration, and run the same set of tests is the previous and next iteration.  *With IF statements of course, so tests that don't apply to the current configuration don't need to be tested.

Is there a way to do this / something similar?

I'm using rails 2.3.8

Comment: This sounds very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7335794/74152 - is it the same situation?

Comment: not quite. Mine is more general.

Comment: It sounds like my answer to that question could be applicable to you in any case - and [the gem](https://github.com/jmerrifield/cuke_iterations) I linked to would be of use.  It lets you specify 'configurations' in an external file with included/excluded tags for each one, then 'tricks' cucumber into running each of your scenarios for each configuration inside a single run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want cucumber example tables, where you can enumerate all your Preference values you want to test the same behavior of:

```
Given I have a preference defined
When I do some thing
Then I should see this behavior

Examples:
  | preference | label_name |
  | foo        | It's Foo!  |
  | bar        | So bar...  |
```

Here's a link to a tutorial using table based examples for testing like this:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/159-more-on-cucumber

Comment: not quite. the preferences are part of the frontend. but the affect the behavior, what gets rendered, etc.  EDIT: nvm, I see what this does. Not quite what I'm lookingfor though. I have a bunch of boolean values that I can mess with. IT would be neat to just iterate over all combinations of them or something.

Comment: would this method work over multiple scenarios? or even multiple files?

Answer (score 3):

Cucumber has a concept called [`Scenario Outlines`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines) that is used to describe a scenario that needs to be run repeatedly with differing data.

Comment: I think I get what you mean by multiple scenarios, but what do you mean by multiple files?

Comment: like.. multiple "features" I don't want to have all my tests in one file.

Comment: Ah, no. I don't believe that outlines can span multiple files.

Comment: Yes. It is highly recommended to split your features into multiple files, based on their contents. For example: a user.feature, search_engine.feature, products.feature, etc. Scenario Outlines can be used in any .feature file.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: And now it's fixed. On SO, feel free to update any entry that you think is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like something you use a scenario outline for:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines

Comment: is there a way to generate that table? My preferences are boolean values. essentially, it'll be like... a 4 bit binary number than I need to iterate over ( the different binary values)

Comment: would this method work over multiple scenarios? or even multiple files?

Comment: If you have 4 booleans and you want to test all configurations, that's 256 tests. If you have more than 4 it will quickly become unmanageable. Generally it's not necessary to test every possible combination. Have a look at http://blog.josephwilk.net/ruby/pairwise-testing-with-cucumber.html